# How to pass event to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Javascript Module Patterns where I am calling a function that will trap enter key into any of the search fields and perform a search operation. The function is being called successfully but the `e.keyCode` is always 0, it is not entering into the condition where `e.keyCode === 13`. I have tried e.which with the same result. My code is below. The issue here is in the `triggerOtherWorkSearch` function.

```
var MyModule = {

    settings: {},

    init: function() {
        this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions: function() {
        $("#searchWork").click(this.otherWorkSearch);
        $("#searchWorkForm").keypress(this.triggerOtherWorkSearch);
    },


    otherWorkSearch: function() {
        if ($("#searchWorkForm").valid()) {
            // Perform search, no issues
        };
    },

    triggerOtherWorkSearch: function (e) {
        alert("keyCode : " + e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("#searchWork").click();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
};

$(function () {
    MyModule.init();
});
```

Comment: looks like it is working fine, post your html too...

Comment: According to the a fiddle, it's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/mjovotzx/. Important to note that you're going to get your scope confused quickly unless you `bind` your functions like: `keypress(this.triggerOtherWorkSearch.bind(this))`.

Comment: One other thing, if you are listening for the enter/return key inside the form, you could probably just listen for the `submit` event instead. Most of the time this would be best, but not necessarily in 100% of cases.

Comment: @Adam, I have changed the bind to $("#searchWorkForm").keypress(this.triggerOtherWorkSearch.bind(this)); but still getting the same result. You might be correct that on that the scope getting confused, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: That was a suggestion, your code works with sensible HTML (see the fiddle from my comment above). Post your HTML - your code works fine. What browser?

Comment: Looks like I had a collision somewhere, the same form id had been used to bind in another place for keypress event. When I saw that the example is working fiddle, I decided to have a closer look. Thanks for pointing it out.